# BrowserMob not working for a preprod proxy

Tags: selenium, browsermob-proxy

I'm using Selenium for automation with C#.  I'm currently running the automation against production together with BrowserMob to stop third party modals displaying whilst running the automation.  This is working perfectly.

I now need to target pre-production which is handled by a proxy.  I can confirm that when using the proxy address the automation launches the browser and hits the pre-production server as expected.  I can confirm this because we have the server address as a html comment in the source code.

My problem is that the blacklist of third parties is then not working when targeting pre-production.

Can anyone help/ suggest how to resolve this please?  Let me know if there's more information you need.

Many thanks,

**C# Code example**

```
ProxyServer = new Server(serverProxyPath, 6666);
ProxyServer.Start();
var httpClient = ProxyServer.CreateProxy();

httpClient.Blacklist(@".*thirdpartydomain.com.*", (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

var proxy = new Proxy
{
   HttpProxy = "1.2.3.4:8080",
   SslProxy = "1.2.3.4:8080"
};
```

[sketch to demonstrate the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xn4WH.png)

Comment: In case of pre-prod proxy, how and where are you setting this pre-prod proxy?

Comment: This is handled by another team.  I'll try and find out some information.  Thanks,

Comment: I use SwitchyOmega in Google Chrome to toggle the proxy.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: I hope you are testing http and not https? else it may become a bit difficult

Comment: whys that?  THanks,

Comment: Because of certificate issuing. I checked and C# doesn't provide a ProxyChain method which Java does for BrowserMobProxy, so you will need to customize the C# browsermob proxy client source code

Comment: ok thank you.  I'll open it up in dotpeek and give an update.  Thanks,